# How to create an open Wifi hotspot with no password in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I was trying to create a wifi hotspot for some experiment, but i was unable to create an open hotspot. Hotspot created is always secured by WPA2 security. Is there any way to create an open hotspot without any password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an open AP using [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) tool.

Install `create_ap`

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
sudo make install
```

Start and enable the service:

```
sudo systemctl start create_ap
sudo systemctl enable create_ap
```

To create an open Access point run the following command:

```
sudo create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint
```

To create an **open Access Point from the same wifi interface**  (`wlan0`) run :

```
sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint
```

**Edit**

To solve the `hostapd not found` error , you should install `hostapd`:

```
sudo apt install hostapd
```

Comment: `sudo systemctl start create_ap` comaand is giving error : `Failed to start create_ap.service: Unit create_ap.service not found.`

Comment: Did you have an error after : `sudo make install` ?

Comment: After running `sudo create_ap wlan0 eth0 MyAccessPoint`  its giving another error `hostapd not found`

Comment: @SnakeEyes install hostapd `apt install hostapd`